# Find latest record with distinct key in table with duplicate keys

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've been trying to find the latest record in a table with distinct key for a table containing duplicate key as in below table:

```
 id        |   user        |   timestamp
-----------+---------------+-------------------------
 aaa       | user_5       | 2015-01-28 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_6       | 2015-01-29 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_1       | 2015-01-24 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_4       | 2015-01-27 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_8       | 2015-01-31 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_2       | 2015-01-25 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_0       | 2015-01-23 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_9       | 2015-01-22 22:28:55.111
 zzz       | user_new     | 2015-01-22 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_3       | 2015-01-26 22:28:55.111
 aaa       | user_7       | 2015-01-30 22:28:55.111
```

The result expected is

```
 id        |   user        |   timestamp
-----------+---------------+-------------------------
 aaa       | user_8       | 2015-01-31 22:28:55.111
 zzz       | user_new     | 2015-01-22 22:28:55.111
```

I couldn't figure out to get the desired result. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number()` is a simple solution:

```
select id, user, timestamp
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query !

```
SELECT 
       id          , 
       user        , 
       timestamp 
FROM 
       [table name]
WHERE 
       timestamp=(SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM [table name])
GROUP BY 
       id
```